# Jest: How to merge coverage reports from different jest test runs

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

Has anyone managed to combine test coverage report from two separate jest test runs?

I am newbie trying to use the default jest coverage reporters: `["json", "lcov", "text", "clover"]`

I have tried using `nyc` to combine `coverage-final*.json` files from tmp folder and output to a `full-test-coverage/` folder.

```bash
npx nyc report --report-dir=full-test-coverage/ --reporter=html -t tmp
```

The full-test-coverage folder is created with index.html etc. However, the combined report is empty.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I was struggling with this too but I managed to do it by using the [istanbul-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-merge) package

So assuming that you want to merge two test coverage named `coverage-final.json` located in two different folders `f1` and `f2`,and name the output `f3/coverage.json` you can do :

`npx istanbul-merge --out coverage.json ./f1/coverage-final.json ./f2/coverage-final.json`

and then use instanbul to create the HTML report :

`npx istanbul report --include coverage.json --dir f3 html`

Comment: ...and it worked :) thanks again @nalmada, much appreciated!!!

Comment: I started with this approach (which works!), but when looking up other options for `istanbul` I discovered the tool's deprecated ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul ).

Comment: I'm running two coverage tests in a monorepo but the reports are on separate levels so to speak, one is at <root> level and the second at <root>/packages/my-app, the combined report loses a lot of the files maybe due to similarly named directoy structure. How do I get the report to be generated properly with all the files included?

Comment: OK, FYI isanbul merge doesnt fail if you dont actually have a coverage-final.json fie

Answer (score 40):

I managed to get it working with nyc. Steps:

- Collect multiple coverage reports using coverage reporter "json"
- Put them all in one directory (which in my case required renaming multiple `coverage-final.json` files)
- `nyc merge multiple-sources-dir merged-output/merged-coverage.json`
- `nyc report -t merged-output --report-dir merged-report --reporter=html --reporter=cobertura`

Comment: Many thanks @jrr for including and highlighting deprecation and highlighting an alternative :)

Comment: For anyone trying this out, I'm still using it and it still works, but I don't have a ton of confidence in the accuracy of the report produced by `nyc merge`, especially when the inputs came from different tools. Related issues: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+merge

Comment: unfortunately the reports are not at all accurate, and significantly underreport coverage levels. nyc appears to be abandoned also.

Comment: so what's the latest tool that could do this in July 2022?

Comment: @peter-poliwoda https://github.com/ljharb/istanbul-merge, see the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008134/39396), here is a script that will collect all the coverage files from multiple yarn workspaces and merge them:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

rm -rf coverage
mkdir -p coverage/workspaces
yarn workspaces foreach -Apv exec bash -c '[ ! -f coverage/coverage-final.json ] && exit 0 || cp coverage/coverage-final.json '$(pwd)'/coverage/workspaces/$(basename $(pwd))-coverage-final.json'
yarn run nyc merge coverage/workspaces coverage/monorepo-coverage.json
yarn run nyc report -t coverage --report-dir coverage/html --reporter=html-spa
```

Note that the `$(pwd)` executes in the script's context (I close and re-open the single quotes around that command) while the other subshells are quoted and will occur in the context of the workspace exec (and so have a CWD of the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, this solution works for me, but my use case was a bit different. I got coverage from two directories in a monorepo, and wanted to merge them in various coverage report types(for other tooling in CI):

1. intall `istanbul-merge` and `nyc` packages (I got v2.0.0 and 15.1.0 respectively)
2. add these three scripts provided that you want to merge the reports after running all tests via `yarn test`:

```
"merge-coverage-report-jsons": "istanbul-merge --out coverage-temp/coverage-final.json packages/ui/coverage/coverage-final.json packages/plugins-core/coverage/coverage-final.json",
"generate-coverage-all-packages": "nyc report --reporter=html --reporter=text --reporter=lcov --reporter=clover --report-dir=coverage --temp-dir=coverage-temp",
"posttest": "yarn merge-coverage-report-jsons && yarn generate-coverage-all-packages",
```